# How do I get my navigation drawer height to fill screen?

Tags: android, layout, navigation-drawer

How do I get my navigation drawer height to fill screen?  As it is, it only wraps content.  I want my navigation drawer to extend to the bottom but have the items in it to remain floating to the top.

[image: I want my navigation drawer to extend to the bottom]

Here is my activity layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"/>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/container"/>

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:id="@+id/pane"/>
        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- The navigation drawer -->
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="#999"
            android:dividerHeight="1dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my drawer layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingStart="10dp"
    android:background="@color/drawer_background">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/drawer_icon"
        android:layout_width="32dp"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:paddingBottom="2dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>

    <TextView
        style="@style/drawer_item"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_item"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:maxLines="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Change the drawer ListView's `background` to something other than `transparent`, like `drawer_background`.

Comment: Uhm, wow, thanks!  That is embarrassing.  I didn't even realize that listview was part of the drawer lol.  Going back to old code is the worst.